# TOMCAT_HOME vs CATALINA_HOME

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I have been updating some documentation lately (we moved from Apache Tomcat 7 to 8) and noticed references to `TOMCAT_HOME`. Such as creating an environment variable `TOMCAT_HOME`. If I'm correct `TOMCAT_HOME` was pretty much deprecated in version 3 and replaced with `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE`? However, I couldn't find any definitive article on this or when to use `TOMCAT_HOME` over `CATALINA_HOME`. Certainly I'm not setting both!? Is there any definitive answer on this? Do popular third party applications look for `TOMCAT_HOME` rather than `CATALINA_HOME`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `TOMCAT_HOME` and there wasn't any. There is only `CATALINA_*` -- still in Tomcat 9. I assume that Mark Thomas did not touch this for compat reasons.

Don't invent your own env variables -- they will only cause confusion.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say that there is no 'TOMCAT_HOME'. Look at these old links: https://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-ccm-list/2004-April/msg00040.html and http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/03/29/tomcat.html?page=2. While these are old links from the archives, they do both reference 'TOMCAT_HOME'. It seems though at some point it got deprecated for CATALINA_HOME?

Comment: @DavidR This is even pre 5.0. It is so old that it is not a reference

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it was the best one, but I think it would be more complete if you updated it to note that TOMCAT_HOME was deprecated a long time ago. I say this because I think the only people who will find this QA useful are those who find themselves looking at TOMCAT_HOME variables in a project they have taken over and wondering what to do with them (like I was).

Comment: @DavidR Tomcat 5.0 was released [ten years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Releases). It is unlikely that someone will touch a software on Tomcat which is older than this.

Comment: you would be surprised Michal

Comment: "there wasn't any" is just wrong, see the comments of DavidR. Strange behaviour to balk against improvement that is.

Answer (score 6):

Tomcat is split into 2 parts. One part is common to all instances of Tomcat. It contains things like the bin and lib directories.

The other part is replicated per-instance. It contains the work, temp and log directories. And conf, which is where the server.xml that defines what ports a given Tomcat instance uses.

So to run (and start/stop) multiple Tomcat instances, you no longer have CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE aimed at the same "TOMCAT_HOME" directory, but instead you have one CATALINA_HOME for all the Tomcats and a separate CATALINA_BASE for each Tomcat.

If you are running multiple instances of Tomcat on a single host you should set CATALINA_BASE to be equal to the .../tomcat_instance1 or .../tomcat_instance2 directory as appropriate for each instance and the CATALINA_HOME environment variable to the common Tomcat installation whose files will be shared between the two instances.